# Can we install multiple vm extensions(custom script) in azure vm at a given point of time.?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to install below two custom vm extensions in Azure VM.
i) Dns forwarder -
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/demos/dns-forwarder/forwarderSetup.sh
ii) crowd strike falcon sensor
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/crowdstrike/falcon-linux-install-bash/main/falcon-linux-deploy.sh

Able to install the above extensions independantly one at a time, but unable to install both vm extensions sequentially one by one. Is there any way we can achieve this ? let me know.

Thanks,
Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can use [`ARM templates`](https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-extensions-customscript-with-template.md) or Azure PowerShell to run multiple scripts on a single custom script extension.***

***I tested the same using [`Azure PowerShell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmextension?view=azps-7.2.0) with the below script :***

```
$fileUri = @("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/demos/dns-forwarder/forwarderSetup.sh",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/crowdstrike/falcon-linux-install-bash/main/falcon-linux-deploy.sh")
$settings = @{"fileUris" = $fileUri ; "commandToExecute" = "sh forwarderSetup.sh && sh falcon-linux-deploy.sh"};
#run command
Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName <rgName> `
    -Location <Location> `
    -VMName <VMName> `
    -Name "testextension" `
    -Publisher "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions" `
    -ExtensionType "CustomScriptForLinux" `
    -TypeHandlerVersion "1.2" `
    -Settings $settings
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: It worked for me. Passing the commands and fileuris as array has worked for me to execute multiple extensions. Thank you

Comment: Glad to be of Help @Kumar